# Subscription add duplicate email message

Tags: php

I create a simple "Subscribe to my newsletter" field on my website.

In the database I have

- **email_id** as the primary
- **emails** set to unique
- **creation** timestamp

If the user is new and signs up, they get redirected to a thank you page.

If something goes wrong, they get redirected to a failed attempt page.

What I need is a page that says, "This email is already in use", if the email is already in the database table.

I guess I could simply make the failed attempt page the email is already in use page, as I don't see what can go wrong since emails is set to unique in the database, but I'm not sure if I should do that or not..?

Here is my code I'm working with. If someone could help me check for duplicate emails so I can display a proper redirect for that I would appreciate it.

```
<?php
include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/core/database.php");

try {

$emails    =    Input::get('emails');
$creation  =    date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$email_id  =    Input::get('email_id');

$insertemail = DB::getInstance()->insert('subscriptions', array(
'emails'   => $emails,
'creation' => $creation,
'email_id' => $email_id,
));


if(!$insertemail) {
header("Location:failed-sub.php"); 


} else {
header("Location:successful-sub.php");
}

} catch(Exception $e) {
?><div class="add-errors"><?php die($e->getMessage()); ?></div><?php  
    }
?>
```

Comment: Maybe on that failed page, instead of saying something went wrong I could say, "We're sorry either that email has already been add or something appears to be wrong with your entry." That way, since it's open to the public, people won't no for sure if that email is in the database or not. I don't know why a hacker would care or not, but it's an option. I'm open to suggestions though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a UX perspective, I would make a failed attempt simply re-load the sign-up page, with an alert above the form that explains why it failed (in this case, the email was already in use).

```
$errors = array();
try {
    $user = User::where('email', Input::get('emails'))->first();

    if ($user) {
        throw new Exception('Email already exists.');
    } else {
        // carry on and create the user
        // redirect to success page
    }

catch (Exception $e) {
    $errors[] = $e->getMessage();
}

if (count($errors)) { ?>
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
       The form failed because:
       <ul>
    <?php
    foreach($errors as $errorMessage) {
        echo "<li>$errorMessage</li>";
    } ?>
       </ul>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
<!-- the rest of your form page -->
```

Note: this example uses a bootstrap theme with the Eloquent ORM for the db stuff.